# How to give read/write permission to a folder for a group

Tags: c#

I have written the following code to give read permission to a group but I am getting anerror:

> "The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted
>   domain failed."

If I am giving a username instead of group, it is working.

```
DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
string group = "groupName";
myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(group,FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Deny));  
myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tafsxecs.aspx) documentation for FileSystemAccessRule:

> Initializes a new instance of the
>   FileSystemAccessRule  class using the
>   name of a user account, a value that
>   specifies the type of operation
>   associated with the access rule, and a
>   value that describes whether to allow
>   or deny the operation.

EDIT: Looks like that constructor is only used with user accounts (you may need the SID for groups).  You should use the constructor that takes an IdentityReference.  Working on an example...

Comment: The IdentityReference param is also defined to link to a user account, not to a group. Are you sure it works well to assign group permissions?